# RegEx to validate just the pattern of First part or full UK postcode

Tags: regex, validation

I know this seems like a duplicate but I have tried all other solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875576/uk-postcode-regex-validation), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23313305/how-to-validate-a-uk-postcode), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012628/uk-postcode-regex), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23309388/validating-a-uk-postcode?lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164979/uk-postcode-regex-comprehensive).

I am looking for a regex which can validate **just the pattern (with space)** of the first part or full UK postcode. I don't want to check for the authenticity of a postcode.

So far I have came up with this

```
((([A-Za-z]?[A-Za-z])[1-9]?([0-9]|[A-Za-z]))|(([A-Za-z]?[A-Za-z])[1-9]?([0-9]|[A-Za-z])\s[1-9][A-Za-z][A-Za-z]))$
```

This seems to work fine for all the patterns. But this also validates the reverse postcode (LastPart FirstPart) eg. `(6FW OX28)`

I am looking for following pattern (copied from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012628/uk-postcode-regex) question)

```
1 Letter  1 Number
1 Letter  2 Numbers
2 Letters 1 Number
2 Letters 1 Number  1 Letter
2 Letters 2 Numbers
1 Letter  1 Number  (Space) 1 Number 2 Letters
1 Letter  2 Numbers (Space) 1 Number 2 Letters
2 Letters 1 Number  (Space) 1 Number 2 Letters
2 Letters 1 Number  1 Letter (Space) 1 Number 2 Letters
2 Letters 2 Numbers (Space) 1 Number 2 Letters
```

Comment: Without any examples (valid and invalid), it is difficult to help. However, perhaps, you just miss the `^` anchor at the beginning of the pattern?

Answer (score 1):

This looks sufficient (updated per comment):

```
^([A-Z]\d{1,2}|[A-Z]{2}\d(\d|[A-Z]?))( \d[A-Z]{2})?$
```

[see test](https://regex101.com/r/vG1oZ3/4)

It includes a long explanation, I'll give a short version

> Basically there are 2 parts, the code can be either only first part, or first then second.
>   First part is `([A-Z]\d{1,2}|[A-Z]{2}\d(\d|[A-Z])?)`
>   Meaning:
>   `[A-Z]\d{1,2}` - a letter and 1-2 digits
>   `|` - OR
>   `[A-Z]{2}\d` - two letters, a digit, then
>   `(\d|[A-Z])?` - either a digit, a letter, or nothing (by using `?` to make it optional).
>   
>   The second part is static - [space][digit][two letters] which is `( \d[A-Z]{2})` it's made optional by using the `?` symbol.

Comment: You forgot about `2 Letters 1 Number  1 Letter (Space) 1 Number 2 Letters` and validate two invalid types of `1 Letter 1 Number  1 Letter` and `1 Letter 2 Numbers 1 Letter` ;).

Comment: @shA.t, thanks, revised. I had the pattern you said was missing, but you were right about validating wrong ones

Comment: How can you make it so it doesn't care whether characters are upper or lowercase?

Comment: @A7DC every place that has `A-Z`, add `a-z`, like `[A-Za-z]`

Answer (score 1):

The best that I can suggest is this:

```
/^[a-z](\d\d?|[a-z]\d[a-z\d]?|[a-z]?\d?\d \d[a-z]{2}|[a-z]\d [a-z] \d[a-z]{2})$/i
```

[[Regex Demo]](https://regex101.com/r/eJ2fA3/2)